# na.strings = “Not Available” resulting in an error

Tags: r

I'm using the below command. I get an error message saying

> "unexpected token".

It is somehow not liking the space between "Not" and "Available" I think. Any help will be appreciated.

```
outcometab <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv",stringsAsFactors=FALSE, na.strings = “Not Available”)
```

Comment: You have curly quotes “” in your code. If they're really there, you need to replace them with regular quotes "".

Comment: Hmm. I just did `outcometab <- read.csv(na.strings="Not Available",
+ text=
+ "1,2,3
+ 4,5,6")`  (`+` signs denote new lines) and it worked fine.

Comment: Curly quotes are often caused by cutting and pasting from MS Word (or even TextEdit on MacOS with default settings ...)

Comment: you both are correct! Replacing with regular quotes did the trick. Thank you so much!